# dzVents - Save 'color' object and reuse

Tags: lua, domoticz

I'd like to get the HUE `color` state, save it, change the color for few minutes and then restore the saved `color`.

The problem is that I can get the `color` state object but I can't restore the previous object as is:

```
return {
    on = {
        devices = {
            'My Light'
        }
    },
    data = {
        savedColor = { initial = {} }
        newColor = { initial = {} }
    },
    execute = function(domoticz, device)
        if (device.active) then
            domoticz.data.savedColor = device.getColor()
            device.setRGB(50,50,50)
            device.switchOff().afterSec(60).forMin(1)

            -- here I'd like to restore the previous state; something like:
            -- device.color = domoticz.data.savedColor
        end
    end
}
```

I do not know how to restore the previous state. I've saved the `color` object but the option to set color is the method `setColor(r, g, b, br, cw, ww, m, t)` that get the single values not the entire object saved!

Comment: how do you "do something for a few minutes" in the first place?

Comment: Update code: for example with `device.switchOff().afterSec(60).forMin(1)`

Comment: and you cannot resolve the previous state because you cannot set the color? because it doesn't work or because you don't know how?
 or is it because you loose the previous state?

Comment: I do not know how to restore the previous state. I've saved the `color` object but the option to set color is the method `setColor(r, g, b, br, cw, ww, m, t)` that get the single values not the entire object.

Comment: and you can't get those parameters from the color object?

Comment: Yes I can! But Why each single params If I want to use the `color` object as is. The idea could be to have a method like: `device.setColor(domoticz.data.savedColor)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/domoticz/domoticz/blob/6edc7436b9e23ff81adaeaf402e2228fe99b1ca9/dzVents/runtime/device-adapters/rgbw_device.lua

device.getColor returns a table

```
local ct = domoticz.utils.fromJSON(device.color, {})
            ct.hue, ct.saturation, ct.value, ct.isWhite = domoticz.utils.rgbToHSB(ct.r, ct.g, ct.b)
            ct.red  = ct.r
            ct.blue = ct.b
            ct.green = ct.g
            ct["warm white"] = ct.ww
            ct["cold white"] = ct.cw
            ct.temperature = ct.t
            ct.mode = ct.m
            ct.brightness = ct.value
            return (ct)
```

And `function device.setColor(r, g, b, br, cw, ww, m, t)` does not accept a table as input.

So the only way is to use the single params. Of course you may write some convenience function that lists those params from a color object, in case you need that more often.

Something like

```
local function color2Params(color)
  return color.r, color.g, color.b,
    color.brightness, color.cw, color.ww, color.m, color.t
end
```

Then you can simply call `device.setColor(color2Params(domoticz.data.savedColor))`

Comment: Ok, thank you! It is a solution... not the best, but works ;-)

Comment: the only alternative you have is to overwrite setColor but then you have to make sure this works everywhere it is used... or write a second function that takes color and does  what my function does internally.